# Thymeleaf cannot find declaration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a problem with thymeleaf. It can not find newUser model in the html file.

```
<form th:action="@{/users/add}" th:object="${newUser}" method="post">
    <p>User Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{userName}"></p>
    <p>Email:     <input type="text" th:field="*{email}"></p>
    <p>Password:  <input type="text" th:field="*{password}"></p>
    <p>Role:
        <select th:field="*{role}">
            <option th:each="role: ${roles}" th:value="${role.getId()}" th:utext="${role.getUserRole()}">
            </option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Add User"></p>
</form>
```

From this class:

```
package Application.Controllers;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TemplateController {

    private final RoleService roleService;

    @Autowired
    public TemplateController(RoleService roleService) {
        this.roleService = roleService;
    }

    @GetMapping("register")
    public String registerUser(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("roles", roleService.listRoles());
        model.addAttribute("newUser", new Users());
        return "redirect:login";
    }
}
```

The problem is that from other class and html it works fine.

Could you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Model attributes are request attributes, but you're performing a redirect. Use session/flash attributes, or change your `/login` handler to add those two attributes itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your LoginUser make sure to add this line:

```
 model.addAttribute("roles", roleService.listRoles());
 model.addAttribute("newUser", new Users());
```

Or change the registerUser return just the view don't redirect to another action:

```
   @GetMapping("register")
    public String registerUser(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("roles", roleService.listRoles());
        model.addAttribute("newUser", new Users());
        return "login";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, second solution worked with return "register", but why I have to define newUser and roles at the login method when redirecting?

Comment: one returns the view while the later redirects to another controller request mapped action